# flex core api hidden

Tags: file, apache-flex

is there any way to change file mode to hidden by flex?

for example 
var myFile:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + File.seperator + "a.txt");
myFile.setHidden

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose you mean Adobe Air, since the File class is not available in Flex.

Still, no, you can't change file attributes. You can access them (`isHidden`, for example) but unfortunatelly they're read-only. Here's the [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) for the `File` class.